# Mapping reference ID to referenced object in entity (Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Is there a way to determine the associated object reference to an ID column in an Entity Framework entity?  For example:

```
class User 
{
    public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
}
```

AccountID is a reference to an Account table, and the Account property is the referenced object that will get lazy loaded.  What I want to determine is that AccountId drives the value in Account.

What I don't want to do is modify the auto-generated files from the EDMX file.  Is there something inside of DbContext or the proxy classes that can provide this information?

Comment: _AccountId drives the value in Account_ - can you elaborate on that?

Answer (score 0):

Can you modify the EDMX? All you would have to do then is go to the User/Account Association, click the "Add Foreign Key" checkbox and rerun the code generation tool. That should fix it for you. [(Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713299)

Comment: If you set the AccountId and run SaveChanges, it will pull the account back if you have lazy-loading set up.